# laravel proper way to extend(expand)/override specific vendor package file

Tags: laravel, extends

the project I involved has `composer require fengqi/hanzi` into the vendor folder, which is used to convert simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese

For people who want to take a look at the package https://github.com/fengqi/hanzi

Inside the vendor folder, the package has the following example directory structure:

```
vendor/
--hanzi/
----src/
------Hanzi.php
------HanziDict.php
------Pinyin.php
```

The specific file **HanziDict.php** I want to modify has a really simple code structure:

```
<?php namespace fengqi\Hanzi;
  return array (
      '啊' => '啊',
       ...
       ...
       'sample char A'=>'sample char B'
 );
```

The github repository of the package suggested that I can insert any "char C => char D" inside the php file if I found the certain chars are missing from the dictionary.

But I believe I should not directly put the code inside vendor folder since it will be override after update.
So, my problem is how I can properly override/extend this file in Laravel (such as insert "char C => char D" into the array).

**I already read and know how to properly extend class outside of vendor folder** but did not find any useful information about other types of php files. I wonder if there is certain ways or rules to do with this kinds of files.

Ideally I want to achieve something like:
outside of the vendor folder, I have an expanded **ExtraHanziDict.php**. So it can always build upon the vendor dict.php.

The following links is the vendor class code (only fewer simple functions to read the dict and convert character)
https://github.com/fengqi/hanzi/blob/master/src/Hanzi.php (apology for throwing the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this case, there's no easy way to change the dictionary. As you correctly guessed you should never change the content of the vendor folder as it's not committed to version control.
In your specific case what you can do is:

1. Ask the repository mantainer to add an api that allows you to add new dictionaries at runtime.
2. Fork the repository, change what you need, and use that instead (see [loading a custom git repository with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654703/loading-a-custom-git-repository-with-composer)). If you think your changes can be useful to others open a Pull request on the original repository.
3. There's no much logic on the repository you linked. Each package you add to your `composer.json` file is a burden, code that doesn't belongs to you and you MUST blindly thrust (what if at some point the repository is hacked and some malicious code hidden into it?). Just create your own service to do such a simple task.

Comment: Is it possible to create a own php dict then extend the the package class to read the dict besides the original dict from package? So as long as I could not find the char in default dict I can go to my own extend dict.

Comment: Hello @Yunhai, yes, sure you could, but again, I'm not sure it is worth for such a small and unmaintained package. In many cases that's actually the way to go but I wouldn't recommend it in this case.

Comment: I fully understand your concern in fact I agree with you in this such small case. But currently I just don't have too many privileges as a front-end (occasionally have to handle some back-end stuffs). Sometimes it's more about communication issues so I just tried to remain certain structures. Anyway, thx for your suggestion